# fill method not working in register controller

Tags: laravel, model, insert, record

after creating my model with model::create facade I use fill method to change the value of "card_tb_name" property but new value doesnt record i should say the "card_tb_name" is declared fillable property .

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Registered;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


/*------------------------------*/

class RegisteredUserController extends Controller
{ 
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'card_tb_name' => 'table_name',
        ]);
        $user->fill(array('card_tb_name' => 'Amsterdam to Frankfurt'));
 }
}
```

Comment: `fill` just sets attributes, it does not do any 'saving' .... you only need that `create` call here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `save()` after `fill()`

```
 $user->fill(array('card_tb_name' => 'Amsterdam to Frankfurt'))->save();
```

Comment: `fill(...)->save()` is what the `update(...)` method does, btw